How do I get performance logs in a specific tab?
I'm using selenium and python on Chrome with the goal of retrieving all the performance logs on tesco.co.uk. However before I go to tesco.co.uk I visit youtube.com, then open tesco on a new tab. This causes the performance logs of both youtube and tesco to be retrieved but I want only tesco's. How can I achieve this?
def get_network_logs:
logs = driver.get_log("performance")
print(logs)
return logs


def switch_to_tab(self, tab_index):
handles = self.driver.window_handles
self.driver.switch_to.window(handles[tab_index])

driver.get('https://www.youtube.com')

switch_to_tab(1)

driver.get('https://www.tesco.co.uk/')

get_networklogs()
 

